# Reading incoming data from barcode

Tags: python, pyserial

I have to read incoming data from a barcode scanner using pyserial. Then I have to store the contents into a MySQL database. I have the database part but not the serial part. can someone show me examples of how to do this. I'm using a windows machine.

Comment: Have you tried the pyserial tutorial, which is part of their documentation? Its very very straightforward to read from a serial port.

Comment: Yeah I did but is it easy to store the data into a database. What format does the data from the scanner come in?

Comment: I have no idea. Do you have a decoded scanner? What barcode symbology are you reading? Perhaps you should look for information on *your* barcode scanner (and hope its decoded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find it easier to use a USB scanner. These will decode the scan, and send it as if it were typed on the keyboard, and entered with a trailing return.

The barcode is typically written with leading and trailing * characters, but these are not sent with the scan.

Thus you print  "*AB123*" using a 3 of 9 font, and when it is scanned sys.stdin.readline().stript() will return "AB123".

There are more than a few options that can be set in the scanner, so you need to read the manual. I have shown the factory default above for a cheap nameless scanner I bought from Amazon.